# Export GeoJSON file automatically in Folium Draw plugin

Tags: python, folium

I have recently been introduced to [folium](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/) and I need to access the exported Geojson file. I found a short code to do for my project.

```
import folium 
from folium.plugins import Draw

m = folium.Map() 
draw = Draw(export=True, 
            filename='data.geojson',
            position='topleft', 
            draw_options={'polyline': False, 
                          'circlemarker': False, 
                          'polygon': False, 
                          'marker': False}, 
            edit_options={'poly': {'allowIntersection': False}}) 

draw.add_to(m) 
m
```

It is straightforward.

Is there any way to save the GeoJSON file automatically after drawing each polygon without clicking on the export button?

I need to access the properties in real time.

Comment: I guess it is not possible using pure folium, but you can embed javascript code using folium. Search for "adding javascript to folium" and "folium draw created save to geojson" etc.